# How do you write a Rsync multi folder shell script like this?

Tags: bash, shell

Source path `/var/www/html/20170101/*.jpg`
Destination path `/Backup/html/20170101/`
There will be a lot of Source path below, such as 20170101, 20171231, a directory with date name, and there will be a lot of graphics in each directory. How do I write a Rsync shell script? I'm using it now
ex:

`Rsync -avzh --progress /var/www/html/20170101/ /Backup/html/20170101/`

I want to write a script that can make the date part of the variable when the day directory is finished, and then change the directory for the next day to continue `Rsync`

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

Put all the directory names in a text file in the below format

cat dirnamefile

```
2017010
20171231
```

Now write a shell script to read the file and substitute the directory each time:

```
i=0
while read line;
do
arr[$i]=`echo $line`
i = `expr $i + 1`
done<dirname

for var in ${arr[@]}
do
Rsync -avzh --progress /var/www/html/$var/ /Backup/html/$var/
done
```

The above script will take in the list of different names for the directories and then loop though running rsync at each loop.

Is this what you are looking for?